# Create Http Client Request Fetch Data Like Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Have a problems and stuck to create http request like axios work with node.js.

For axample :

```
axios.get('http://url')
  .then(response => {

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
  });
```

What happened in (axios) code, so we can get data. I Want to create the same with node.js without three library and not use Fetch API or XHR.

I Want to create class

```
Class MyCode {
 static get(){
//mycode stuck
 }
}
```

so we can get data trough

MyCode.get('url').then....catch....

Thankyou

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to understand how to actually parse the response object from the Axios returned promise?

Comment: I want to create the same with axios.

for example i can crete with my code :

MyCode.get('http....').then....catch...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
var http=require('http');
var req=http.request('http://url',{'method':'methodtype',headers:{'Content-Type':'text/plain'}},(res)=>{
   res.on('data',(data)=>{
     console.log(`data is ${data}`);
   });

});
req.on('error',(err)=>{
    console.log('error -->',err);
});

req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class using an existing request module(whatever npm module you choose). Take a look at this example, it may be useful.

```
'use strict';

const defaultRequest = require('request-promise-native');

class MyCode {
    constructor({
        request = defaultRequest,
    } = {}) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    async get({
        method = 'GET',
        headers = {},
        body,
        url,
        ...rest
    }) {
        try {
            return this.request(Object.assign(
                {
                    url,
                    method,
                    headers,
                    body,
                },
                rest,
            ));
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}


async function test() {
    let x = new MyCode();
    const response = await x.get({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    });

    console.log(response);
}

test();
```